# Properly format m3u playlist

Tags: xbmc, m3u8, m3u

I am using XBMC to watch IPTV, simple created playlist like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Pink Action
http://on108.setplex.net/fastv_2....ca.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1,Pink Action 2
http://on108.setplex.net/fastv_2....ca.m3u8
#EXTINF:0,KISS RADIO
http://213.246.53.21:9515/
#EXTINF:0,KRAJISKI RADIO GRMEC
http://95.211.166.127:8234/
```

The problem is here because on menu in XBMC i have menu TV but all streams, RADIO and TV are together, is ti possible to seperate them in one m3u. With that properly format than i think in XBMC i will get second menu RADIO?

Question is how to properly format m3u list, with RADIO and TV, and also how to add logo of the channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is properly formated m3u

```
#EXTINF:-1,tvg-id="Pink Action" tvg-name="Pink Action" tvg-logo="Pink Action.png" group-title="TV", Pink Action

tvg-id= name of the channel EPG
tvg-logo= name of the logo (XBMC/Logo/PinkAction.png) folder
group-title= groups
and finaly name of the channel
```

Comment: Is there a language attribute?